# Div structure, same auto widths for every column

Tags: html, css

lets see this table:

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td>1111</td><td>42342324</td><td>ffffffff</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>442324</td><td>fdadasdfffffff</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to do something like that but with DIV elements (sorry, boss wont allow tables). The real problem is, how to set same widths without direct setting it? I mean, if the first row is longer, then it will be actual width, otherwise the 2nd row's.
Preferably without javascript/jQuery hacking.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Rule number 1: Never say sorry for not being allowed to use tables

Comment: If you're complaining that your boss won't let you use tables; and you don't realize that your boss is one of the very few out there who evidently knows a little bit about this sort of stuff, you may need to spruce up your skills a bit http://blog.silktide.com/2011/04/why-you-shouldnt-use-tables-for-layout-ever/

Comment: What axrwkr said. That said, the `table` tag is not 100% evil. It just should not be used for _layout_ purposes. If you have tabular data, then by all means, use tables, and when your boss questions it, tell him tabular data belongs in tables. Dunno your situation but I know semi-technical people who heard "you shouldn't use tables for layout" and then promptly forgot the last two words, and thought the `table` tag was some relic from the past that should never be used...kinda like `blink` =0P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the "columns" to grow in width together with the content? dynamically setting the width of each div in the column?

I can't think of a way to do this with css, but some jiggery pokery with some divs might work.

```
<style>
    .table{
      border:1px solid black;
      position:relative;
    }
    .column{
      border:1px solid red;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .cell{
      border:1px solid blue;
      float:left;
      clear:both;
    }
</style>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="column">
            <div class"cell">11</div>
            <div class"cell">ffff</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class"cell">1111</div>
            <div class"cell">f</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class"cell">1</div>
            <div class"cell">fff</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check out `flexbox` for modern browsers, with a JavaScript fallback for older browsers.

http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

> Flexbox is pretty awesome and is certainly part of the future of layout. The syntax has changed quite a bit over the past few years, hence the "Old" and "New" syntax. But if we weave together the old, new, and in-between syntaxes, we can get decent browser support. Especially for a simple and probably the most common use case: order-controlled grids

http://caniuse.com/flexbox shows pretty decent support.. IE10, FF, Chrome, Safari, and even Opera! *

*using combined "old and new" syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="main_div">
  <div id="nr1">   </div>
  <div id="nr2">   </div>
</div>
```

and you use css to style : width ,height ,margin ,position of each div

Comment: how ever if you wish to generate a large number of divs inside "main_div" and you want them all to be identical use class instead of id , and wrap the class into a while